# My object isn't reflects the light in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some CubeGeometry based mesh in a three.js scene, and all of them reflects the PointLight what I'm using globally. But one of them, which made by "hand" with just THREE.Geometry (add vertices and faces by code) is not reflected. Even it has no color, I only can set color for this, if I set a THREE.Color to "emissive" key on the MeshPhongMaterial.

The geometry made by a JS function dinamically. I'm using this litghs:

```
    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFEF0, 1, 100000)
    pointLight.position = camera.position;
    scene.add(
        pointLight
    );
```

And I'm creating the mentioned mesh with this code:

```
        var floor = new THREE.Mesh(
            ShelfArchitect.Utils.getFloorGeometry(walls), 
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(materialParams)
        );
```

I should add something on materialParams? Or what is the problem?

Comment: I just create the geometry width var geom = new THREE.Geometry();, and  add some vertices with geom.vertices.push( ... ), and some faces with geom.faces.push( ... ) . What else should I do next? After your answer, I tried to call geom.computeVertexNormals(), but it still doesn't work.
Thank you

Comment: `computeVertexNormals()` requires `computeFaceNormals()` first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the geometry made by "hand" is missing, or has incorrect, vertex normals.

You can do this:

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Comment: `computeFaceNormals` does not look like something that exists

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Correct. This question pertained to an old version of three.js.

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty new to three.js and I hardly distinguish what's old by what's new